# Will Angular 2 child routes refresh the parent route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have an application in which I route between children of a parent route in some situations. One will look like `example.com/a/1/` another `example.com/a/2/` will switching from `1` to `2` trigger a reload/render of the page `a`?

Like playing a video in `a` and have a routes outlet as sibling to that video, will this change of page trigger the video to reload?

If so, can this be prevented?

Comment: I am too having this issue...!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it won't. The parent component will only be refreshed if you navigate away from it and then navigate to it again.

Comment: I am using
`this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    }`
I need the reuse strategy but the parent also gets initialized...Pls suggest a workaround

Comment: Is their any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution:

```
constructor(private _router:Router,private _activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){}
this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) { 
    // this._activatedRoute.snapshot is up to date
  }
});
```

Works like a charm

Credit: [Angular Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12912)

Solution by @skreborn

Thanks