# Navigate to child route without reloading parent route (component)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, router

Lets say active route is:

http://localhost:4200/job/1/overview

When user navigate to different child route lets say candidates

http://localhost:4200/job/1/candidates

I want only latest segment overview to be changed to candidates without reloading parent route again (parent component is reloading again and it is slower and doing whole process again).

**job module route**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'overview',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: JobOverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'candidates',
        component: CandidatesComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Function where I am changing route:

```
navigate(value) {
  this.route.navigate(['/job/' + this.selectedJobId + value]);
}
```

Tried in navigate method to call ../value and some other approaches but nothing.. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

component html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="app-sidebar" data-active-color="white" data-background-color="black" >
        <!-- data-image="assets/img/sidebar-bg/01.jpg" -->
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        <div class="sidebar-background"></div>
    </div>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="main-panel">    
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <app-footer></app-footer> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In app-sidebar component i am calling this navigate function to navigate to different child route. But this is the html component where i am showing routes for job module (and of course job module children).

Similar issue already found:

[Will Angular 2 child routes refresh the parent route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642727/will-angular-2-child-routes-refresh-the-parent-route)

but still does not work for me.

Comment: How does your `component.html` look like?

Comment: @karoluS updated my question.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the error but you should use navigate method like this `this.route.navigate(['/job', this.selectedJobId, value]);` angular will concat those values itself.

Comment: @karoluS if i use it like you said it does not concatenate ... it is  going to job/1 and that is... I added edit where i find something similar but i tried that and same again...

Comment: It look like the value is null and it falls into overview route. Can you navigate to `candidates`?

Comment: @karoluS noup value is not null and yes i can navigate to candidates.